# two (2) table view on one (1) view controller

Tags: xcode, ipad, uitableview

is it possible to have 2 table view controllers in 1 view controller? And can you help with this?

I'm making a simple app that requires 2 tableview to present the client database and the "Activity" of a selected client. so, 2 table view will be needed to populate the client list and the Activity Lists.
This application will be used on an iPad.

Comment: yes, it is possible. what kind of assistance do you really need?

Comment: after a few more minutes of looking around, I found the article I need - "Loading multiple tableviews in a UIView (UIView Controller)" form StackOverflow. thank you for your quick reply :)